# Drawing multiple line + ribbon plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data set looks like this

```
sample_data <- structure(list(chrom = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 
                                                .Label = c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3", "chr4"), 
                                                class = "factor"), 
                              sample = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                                                 .Label = c("sample_1", "sample_2"), 
                                                 class = "factor"),
                              average = c(358.017, 34.452, 409.7959, 117.0805, 345.6717, 34.3544, 362.3519, 110.7264), 
                              std_dev = c(1484.33280699, 97.332895241, 1460.24099656, 
                                          519.299214731, 1439.86318396, 114.04659662, 1340.67100158, 
                                          499.901605662)), 
                         .Names = c("chrom", "sample", "average", "std_dev"), 
                         row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L), class = "data.frame")


> sample_data
   chrom   sample  average   std_dev
1   chr1 sample_1 358.0170 1484.3328
2   chr2 sample_1  34.4520   97.3329
3   chr3 sample_1 409.7959 1460.2410
4   chr4 sample_1 117.0805  519.2992
25  chr1 sample_2 345.6717 1439.8632
26  chr2 sample_2  34.3544  114.0466
27  chr3 sample_2 362.3519 1340.6710
28  chr4 sample_2 110.7264  499.9016
```

I want to make a line plot for each `sample` `average` (y) per `chrom` (x), with a ribbon showing the standard deviation (`std_dev`) range. So I came up with this code:

```
sample_ribbon <- ggplot(sample_data, x=chrom, y=average, group=sample)
sample_ribbon <- sample_ribbon + geom_line()
sample_ribbon <- sample_ribbon + geom_ribbon(aes(x=chrom, ymin=average - std_dev, ymax=average + std_dev), alpha = 0.3)
print(sample_ribbon)
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Error in order(data$PANEL, data$group, data$x) : 
argument 3 is not a vector
```

Any idea what is wrong with this? I have tried multiple methods to plot this and they all come back with this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the first line of ggplot to include aes and it will work:

```
sample_ribbon <- ggplot(sample_data, aes(x=chrom, y=average, group=sample))
```

The rest are fine.

```
 sample_ribbon <- sample_ribbon + geom_line()
 sample_ribbon <- sample_ribbon + geom_ribbon(aes(x=chrom, ymin=average - std_dev, ymax=average + std_dev), alpha = 0.3)
 print(sample_ribbon)
```

[image]